# ERROR: Unable to load libphutil

Tags: php, include-path, phabricator, libphutil

We have setup running `Phabricator` in one of our servers. Today I upgrade it by following the standard steps given in "https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/upgrading/" upgrade note.

When I try to start `pdh` using `systemctl start phabricator-phd` it get fails.

Error is

```
ERROR: Unable to load libphutil. Update your PHP 'include_path' to include the parent directory of libphutil/.
```

I tried other different way to start it but all of the giving this same error.
Hope someone can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

in the folder where `arcanist/` is

```
git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Take a look at that repo now. There's nothing in it! https://github.com/phacility/libphutil. Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278745/error-unable-to-load-libphutil/60764589#60764589.

Answer (score 1):

Using `git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git` [like @Youngjae Ji recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190014/4561887) doesn't work anymore. Take a look at that repo now. There's nothing in it! https://github.com/phacility/libphutil. A work-around seems to be the following, however:

`sudo apt install libphutil` then `dpkg -L libphutil` to see where it's located on your system. Once you find out where it is (ex: **/usr/share/libphutil**), symbolically link to it in arcanist as follows: `ln -s /usr/share/libphutil path_to_arcanist/externals/includes`. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `phd` is restarted via `bin/phd restart`. Does this work? If yes, then the issue is your startup script. If no, then Phabricator likely wasn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
It was a permission issue. below fixed it.

```
chmod g+rX,o+rX libphutil/ -Rc
chmod g+rX,o+rX arcanist/ -Rc
chmod g+rX,o+rX phabricator/ -Rc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.One way to solve: just put libphutil, arcanist, phabricator(the websever started) on same path